# function that returns the string after ","

Tags: vba

I need to write a function that returns the second expression from a comma-separated string.
I tried to write with an array

```vb
Function ReturnSecString() As Variant
    Dim myarr As Variant
 
    ReDim myarr(2)
    
    myarr(0) = "My"
    myarr(1) = "Name"
    myarr(2) = "Is"
    
    ReturnSecString = myarr
End Function
 
Sub TestTransposeArray()
    Dim outputArr As Variant
    'Call Return Function

    outputArr = ReturnSecString()
    MsgBox outputArr(2)
End Sub
```

It does print the second word for me, but I need a function that will print the second word in the entire line after a comma.

Comment: Is your question for VBA or VB.NET? Can you give an example of such a line?  Where are you stuck? You are aware of functions like `Instr` and `Split`?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a string like "String1, I am String2, String3" and you want to return "I am String2" only?

Comment: Exactly.Im Working on VBA.

Answer (score 1):

### Return Nth Substring

- This will allow you to choose which substring to return and which delimiter to use.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function returnNthString(ByVal InitialString As String, _
                         Optional ByVal NthSubString As Long = 1, _
                         Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
         As String
    Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Split(InitialString, Delimiter)
    On Error Resume Next
    returnNthString = myArr(NthSubString - 1)
End Function
 
Sub TESTreturnNthString()
    Const InitialString As String = "Apple, Banana , Orange, Plum"
    Debug.Print returnNthString(InitialString, 2)
    ' Result: Banana
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

   Dim t As String
   t = "String1, I am String2, String3"
   
   Dim x As String
   x = SecondStringAfterComma(t)
   
   Debug.Print x
   
End Sub

Function SecondStringAfterComma(sent As String) As String

    Dim ret As String
    ret = Split(sent, ",")(1)

    SecondStringAfterComma = ret
    
End Function
```

Result

```
 I am String2
```

Comment: `myArr` as parameter name is a little bit misleading as the parameter needs to be of type String. And if you write a function that is basically just a wrapper around `Split`, I think it should check if the second element exists at all

Comment: @FunThomas - good point on checking for existence, since the function is just a wrapper - which my foggy brain didn't even realize this morning ...